# VLCj get Snapshot at the last millisecond

Tags: vlcj

I'm using VLCj 2.4.1 and want to take screenshot at the last millisecond of the video. Usually I just do

```
getMediaPlayer().setTime(someTime);
getMediaPlayer().getSnapshot();
```

and it works. But if `someTime` is `>= getMediaPlayer().getLength()-120` (I get to 120ms through experimentation) VLCj doesn't respond (video position stays the same).

If however `someTime` is in range `0-getMediaPlayer().getLength()-120` everything works as expected.

Where is the problem? Why are those `~120ms` "missing"?

Comment: I can't speak for those "missing" milliseconds specifically, but setTime() is asynchronous - it looks like you may be assuming it operates synchronously.

Comment: I have `Thread.sleep(3000);` in between so it does have time to position itself. The thing is it doesn't move after 500ms, 1s, or even 5s if `someTime` is >= `getMediaPlayer().getLength()-120`. `setPosition(1.0)` same thing (nothing happens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the problem with completely different program/library - Xuggle for Java. It works flawlessly - see [DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java)